# Add multiple star rating in the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I,m trying to add a star rating functionality to my page in mvc , but when i tried to loop over them in the view i got the problem which is all of stars are attached to the first on which mean when i change the second one the first one changes , i got the code from internet 
can any one help

```
fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
 border: none;
 float: left;
  }

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
 margin: 5px;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "\f005";
  }

 .rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
   }

   .rating > label { 
    color: #ddd; 
    float: right; 
     }

     /***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

    .rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
     .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
      .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } 
       /*        hover previous stars in list */

       .rating > input:checked + label:hover,
       .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
       .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
       .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

HTML :

```
  <h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems, when you try to insert this same code multiple times:

- in HTML there should be only 1 element with a particular **ID**
- input radio elements group together by **NAME** attribute, meaning if all your input have the same name (eg. rating), then all your radio inputs are changing the value for that variable

This is how you fix this:

1. You should add a unique identifier to the ID of each separate fieldset block
2. You should use separate name attribute in each fieldset block

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/uf3opady/5/

The code (please note that I used the *_1* and *_2* suffix for the **ID, FOR and NAME attributes** in the code:

```
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5_1" name="rating_1" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5_1" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half_1" name="rating_1" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half_1" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4_1" name="rating_1" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4_1" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half_1" name="rating_1" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half_1" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3_1" name="rating_1" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3_1" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half_1" name="rating_1" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half_1" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2_1" name="rating_1" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2_1" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half_1" name="rating_1" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half_1" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1_1" name="rating_1" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1_1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf_1" name="rating_1" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf_1" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>

<br><br><br>

<h1>2nd Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5_2" name="rating_2" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5_2" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half_2" name="rating_2" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half_2" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4_2" name="rating_2" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4_2" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half_2" name="rating_2" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half_2" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3_2" name="rating_2" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3_2" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half_2" name="rating_2" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half_2" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2_2" name="rating_2" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2_2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half_2" name="rating_2" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half_2" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1_2" name="rating_2" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1_2" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf_2" name="rating_2" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf_2" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```